# vb6 ADODB TSQL procedure call quit working after database migration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, vb6

This code was once working on sql server 2005.  Now isolated in a visual basic 6 sub routine using ADODB to connect to a sql server 2008 database it throws an error saying:

"Login failed for user 'admin' "

I have since verified the connection string does work if i replace the body of this sub with the alternative code below this sub. When I run the small program with the button, it stops where it is marked below the asterisk line.  Any ideas?  thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim cSQLConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmdGetInvoices As New ADODB.Command
Dim myRs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim dStartDateIn As Date
dStartDateIn = "2010/05/01"


cSQLConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb;" _
         & "SERVER=NET-BRAIN;" _
         & "Database=DB_app;" _
         & "User Id=admin;" _
         & "Password=mudslinger;"

cSQLConn.Open

 cmdGetInvoices.CommandTimeout = 0


    sProc = "GetUnconvertedInvoices"
    'On Error GoTo GetUnconvertedInvoices_Err

    With cmdGetInvoices
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "_sp_cwm5_GetUnCvtdInv"
        .Name = "_sp_cwm5_GetUnCvtdInv"
        Set oParm1 = .CreateParameter("@StartDate", adDate, adParamInput)
        .Parameters.Append oParm1
        oParm1.Value = dStartDateIn
        .ActiveConnection = cSQLConn

    End With

    With myRs
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
        .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
        '.CursorType = adOpenStatic
        .CacheSize = 5000
        '***************************Debug stops here
        .Open cmdGetInvoices

    End With


    If myRs.State = adStateOpen Then
            Set GetUnconvertedInvoices = myRs
    Else
            Set GetUnconvertedInvoices = Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

Here is the code which validates the connection string is working.

```
Dim cSQLConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmdGetInvoices As New ADODB.Command
Dim myRs As New ADODB.Recordset

    cSQLConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb;" _
             & "SERVER=NET-BRAIN;" _
             & "Database=DB_app;" _
             & "User Id=admin;" _
             & "Password=mudslinger;"
cSQLConn.Open

 cmdGetInvoices.CommandTimeout = 0


    sProc = "GetUnconvertedInvoices"


    With cmdGetInvoices
    .ActiveConnection = cSQLConn
    .CommandText = "SELECT top 5 * FROM tarInvoice;"
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    End With

    With myRs
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
        '.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
        .CursorType = adOpenStatic
        '.CacheSize = 5000
        .Open cmdGetInvoices
    End With

    If myRs.EOF = False Then
        myRs.MoveFirst
        Do
            MsgBox "Record " & myRs.AbsolutePosition & " " & _
          myRs.Fields(0).Name & "=" & myRs.Fields(0) & " " & _
          myRs.Fields(1).Name & "=" & myRs.Fields(1)
          myRs.MoveNext
        Loop Until myRs.EOF = True
    End If
```

Comment: If you look in the SQL Server error log you should see a login failed message and an error state number matching one in this list.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366351.aspx What state does it show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a linked database permissions error in sql server 2008.  I had to delete the link and recreated it with a login/password.

Answer (score 0):

This probably shouldn't cause the error you're seeing, but according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677593(VS.85).aspx:

"Only a setting of adOpenStatic is supported if the CursorLocation property is set to adUseClient. If an unsupported value is set, then no error will result; the closest supported CursorType will be used instead."